# Consume netcdf Data with ESRI Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, netcdf

We've got loads of raster data that can be organized by time, so we thought packaging them into netCDF would be a good a idea.  But we also want to serve out the data to a web application that leverages the ArcGIS javascript api.  I've seen the [ncWMS](http://www.resc.rdg.ac.uk/trac/ncWMS/) page, but the info there doesn't exactly make it clear how to consume the ncWMS.  Anybody have experience with this or/could point me to an example?

Answer (score 2):

We use ncWMS to deliver WMS services from time series of gridded data, and now that ncWMS has been folded into the Unidata THREDDS Data Server, we can just turn on the WMS service for any dataset.  Here's an example using the excellent PRISM climate data: http://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/prism3.html?dataset=prism3/monthly
If you click on the "godiva2" link at the bottom of the page, you will launch the godiva2 web client, which is a consumer of the WMS services provided by ncWMS (in this case embedded in the THREDDS Data Server)